# Django Models: How to express the following logic...?

Tags: database, django, django-models, many-to-many, one-to-many

I'm facing a difficulty on a schema and i need help with the following logic.

I have a table `Client` and a table `Rights`. The table `Client` represents a client with some properties and the table `Rights` the available rights for each client.

So, i want to assign to a client a list of available rights (each user can have different rights but all are from the table `Rights`), how can i do it in models?

After that how can i retrieve for a `Client` the `Rights` assigned to him?

#### Client

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
website = models.URLField(null=True)
```

#### Rights

```
key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, db_index=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ManyToManyField

```
class Rights(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(null=True)
    rights = models.ManyToManyField(Rights)
```

You can get all the rights for a client using

```
c = Client.objects.get(id=1)
rights = c.rights.all()
```

Comment: Question: The `rights = c.rights.all()` will be instance of `Rights` or instance of the `Client`?

Comment: `rights` will be a queryset and will tell you all the rights assigned to client `c`. `c` is an instance of Client.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field in your Client model. After all, this is a many-to-many relationship.

If each right is unique to each client, then use a ForeignKey from a Right to a Client instead.

Answer (score 1):

Jorge, sorry I don't have enough karma to reply directly to your comment.

```
Question: The rights = c.rights.all() will be instance of Rights or instance of the Client?
```

-> `Rights` instances.

All `Rights` instances linked to the `Client` object.

Comment: I've made some tests on that and i found that does not recognize it neither as `Right` or `Client` but instead as `django.db.models.query.QuerySet`. Example: `isinstance(<variable_instance>, django.db.models.query.QuerySet)` gives `True`

Comment: Yes it's a queryset that contains Rights instances. `print rights[0]`